# Second Highest Salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Write a SQL query to get the second highest salary from the Employee table.

```
    | Id | Salary |
    | 1  | 100    |
    | 2  | 200    |
    | 3  | 300    |
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the query should return 200 as the second highest salary. If there is no second highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
    | SecondHighestSalary |
    | 200                 |
```

This is a question from Leetcode, for which I entered the following code:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN Salary = '' 
                THEN NULL
    ELSE Salary 
    END AS SecondHighestSalary 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 2 Salary
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Num
          FROM Employee
          ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS T
    WHERE T.Num = 2
```

It says that the query does not return NULL if there's no value for second highest salary. 
 For eg. if the table is

```
   | Id | Salary| 
   | 1  |  100  |
```

The query should return

```
   |SecondHighestSalary|
   |       null        |
```

and not

```
   |SecondHighestSalary|
   |                   |
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-query-to-find-second-largest-salary/

Comment: "Second highest" is ambiguous. What do you want to do in case of a tie? E.g. add another record with salary 300 to your sample table. Then: do you want to show 300 or 200? You must answer this question first, before you can write the query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner even in case of tie, it should display the next highest value, no matter how many times the first highest value is repeated. If no second highest value is present, then it should return NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of ties you want the second highest distinct value. E.g. for values 100, 200, 300, 300, you want 200.

So get the highest value (`MAX(salary)` => 300) and then get the highest value less than that:

```
select max(salary) from mytable where salary < (select max(salary) from mytable);
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution to the Leetcode 2nd highest salary problem is:

```
Select 
    Max(Salary) AS SecondHighestSalary 
from Employee 
    where Salary < (
                     Select Max(Salary) from Employee
                   );
```

Answer (score 2):

Using window functions, utilizing NTH_VALUE gives a clean answer

```sql
SELECT ( 
SELECT NTH_VALUE(Salary, 2) OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Salary
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 ) AS SecondHighestSalary
;
```

##### Detailed Break-Down:

1. The outer SELECT Statement is required to get NULL value incase a value was not found (second rank is not present for example, or table only has one row)
2. NTH_VALUE(Salary, 2) is basically saying, look at each group (in our case it divides the table based on groups of Salary) and for each group add a column that lists the second highest value, for every row within the same group from that new column, we want to pick the second most paid (so only second row)
3. NTH_VALUE() OVER(ORDER BY) is in ASC order by default, make sure you explicit the DESC order
4. NTH_VALUE() merely gives the order to the rows within each group (here Salary) incase of two similar salaries in the same salary group it will give them separate ranks (ex 1 and 2) even if they have same value in the same group, For this use GROUP BY () statement
5. Because NTH_VALUE() merely gives the order to the columns, based on a group USE LIMIT 1 to get just one value (top value) and OFFSET 1 (to make that top value our targeted second most paid)

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do that with OFFSET 1/FETCH 1:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: OFFSET/ FETCH helps in returning the second highest value if there are two or more different salaries, but it doesn't help in returning NULL if there's only one value for the salary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RANK() function to rank the values for Salary column, along with a CASE statement for returning NULL.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MAX(SalaryRank) = 1 THEN NULL ELSE Salary as SecondHighestSalary
FROM
(
 SELECT *, RANK()OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) As SalaryRank
 FROM Employee 
) AS Tab
WHERE SalaryRank = 2
```

It would be better to use the DENSE_RANK() function so that ranks don't get skipped whenever there is a tie for a position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if there's no value as the Second Highest, for eg. if there only one row in the master table, then even using rank does not return NULL. It returns ' ' value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, MAX(salary) AS salary 
FROM employee 
WHERE salary IN
(SELECT salary FROM employee MINUS SELECT MAX(salary) 
FROM employee);
```

You can try above code to find 2nd maximum salary. 
The above code uses MINUS operator.
For further reference use the below links 
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-query-to-find-second-largest-salary/

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DENSE_RANK()` & do `LEFT JOIN` with employee table :

```
SELECT t.Seq, e.*
FROM ( VALUES (2) 
     ) t (Seq) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT e.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Num
      FROM Employee e
     ) e 
     ON e.Num = t.Seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a CTE (from MSSQL 2005 or newer) or ROWNUMBER the easiest and more "portable" way is to just order by twice using a subquery.

```
select top 1 x.* from
(select top 2 t1.* from dbo.Employee t1 order by t1.Salary) as x
order by x.Salary desc
```

The requisite to show null when there's not a second bigger salary is a bit more tricky but also easy to do with a if.

```
if (select count(*) from dbo.Employee) > 1
begin
    select top 1 x.* from
    (select top 2 emp.* from dbo.Employee emp order by emp.Salary) as x
    order by x.Salary desc
end
else begin
    select null as Id, null as Salary
end
```

Obs:. OP don't said what to do when the second largest is a tie with the first but using this solution is a simple matter of using a DISTINCT in the IF subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE a
    ([Id] int, [Salary] int)
;
     
INSERT INTO a
    ([Id], [Salary])
VALUES
    (1, 100),
    (2, 200),
    (3, 300)
;

GO
SELECT Salary as SecondHighestSalary
FROM a 
ORDER BY Salary 
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

```
| SecondHighestSalary |
| ------------------: |
|                 200 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy way to do this

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM table WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for getting n-th highest salary, where n = 1,2,3....(int)

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM (
   SELECT TOP n salary 
   FROM employees 
   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

Hope this will help you. Below is one of the implementation.

```
create table #salary (salary int)
insert into #salary values (100), (200), (300)

SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM (
   SELECT TOP 2 salary 
   FROM #salary 
   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary ASC

drop table #salary
```

The output is here 200 as 300 is first highest, 200 is second highest and 100 is the third highest as shown below

```
salary
200
```

Here n is 2

Answer (score 0):

```
select case 
when cnt>1 then SecondHighestSalary
else null end as SecondHighestSalary
from 
(select top 1 Salary as SecondHighestSalary,
(select count(distinct Salary)  from Employee) as cnt 
from (
select distinct top 2 Salary 
from Employee
order by Salary desc ) as sal
order by SecondHighestSalary asc) as b
```

Comment: We can keep track of distinct count of the total records in the table. If table has more then one distinct count, it means it has SecondHighestSalary otherwise it has no Second Highest Salary

Answer (score 0):

Select salary from employees limit 1,1 ;

### Very easy way to find second highest salary

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  case when max(salary) is null then null else max(salary) end SecondHighestSalary 
from (
  select salary , dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rn
  from Employee
)r
where rn = 2
```

[This code returns null when there is no second highest salary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6EpM.png)

Comment: Could you rephrase? As it is, it is not very lisible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the union condition to handle the null case

```sql
SELECT Salary as "SecondHighestSalary" from Employee 
WHERE Salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee )    
UNION
(SELECT null)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists() together with If-else statements.

Query:

```
If exists(select distinct salary as SecondHighestSalary from employee
order by salary desc offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only) 

select distinct salary as SecondHighestSalary from employee
order by salary desc offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only

else select null as SecondHighestSalary;
```

Answer (score 0):

#Please check the below code#

```
SELECT TOP 1 secondhighestsalary 
  FROM (SELECT  
        CASE WHEN z.SalaryRank >1 THEN Salary 
        ELSE null END secondhighestsalary, SalaryRank 
        FROM 
(SELECT salary, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) As SalaryRank 
FROM Employee GROUP  BY salary )z 
GROUP BY Salary, SalaryRank 
)c 
ORDER BY secondhighestsalary DESC
```

## Explanation:

** SELECT salary, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) As SalaryRank
FROM Employee GROUP  BY salary**

above query is to provide rank to Salary column, group by clause will take care the duplicate values ..... next

**SELECT
CASE WHEN z.SalaryRank >1 THEN Salary
ELSE null END secondhighestsalary, SalaryRank
FROM
(SELECT salary, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) As SalaryRank
FROM Employee GROUP  BY salary )z **

next piece of code assign NULL against rank 1 and salary for greater than 1 rank.

So if you have only one row in the table and as per our question we need to display second highest salary if not display NULL, it will take care that situation.

At last we need to Order by DESC and take the  Top 1 record.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. It would really help our readers if you could explain why and how your answer solves the OPs problems

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas, please find the explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT max(Salary) as SecondHighestSalary from Employee where salary <>(SELECT max(salary) from Employee)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query which solves all test cases of LeetCode

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM Employee) > 1
BEGIN
  WITH T AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT e.salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY e.salary DESC) AS rnk FROM Employee e)
  SELECT salary AS SecondHighestSalary FROM T WHERE rnk = 2
END
ELSE BEGIN
  SELECT NULL AS SecondHighestSalary
END
```