# To find the Nth Highest Salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the `Employee` table (SQL Server)

```
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
```

For this example, the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
| getNthHighestSalary(2) |
+------------------------+
| 200                    |
```

Is there any way to write this query other than by using function?

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? You've tagged both SQL Server 2008 and 2012, which one are you *really* using?

Comment: This will point you in the right direction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second Highest Salary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296941/second-highest-salary)

Comment: @Larnu I was trying using function, but found it to be too complicated. And using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Its a question in leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/)

Answer (score 6):

Another possible approach is using ROW_NUMBER() or DENSE_RANK() functions. It is important to know if there can be more then one salary at or before Nth position.

```
CREATE TABLE #Salary (
    [id] int,
    [salary] numeric(10, 2)
)

INSERT #Salary 
    ([id], [salary])
VALUES
    (1, 100),
    (2, 500),
    (3, 200),
    (4, 300),
    (5, 200);

DECLARE @Position int = 2;

-- With possible duplicate salaries
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        [id], [salary],
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [salary] ASC) AS [DRPosition]
    FROM #Salary
)
SELECT [id]
FROM cte
WHERE [DRPosition] = @Position
ORDER BY [DRPosition];

-- Without possible duplicate salaries
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        [id], [salary],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [salary] ASC) AS [RPosition]
    FROM #Salary
)
SELECT [id]
FROM cte
WHERE [RPosition] = @Position
ORDER BY [RPosition]
```

Answer (score 5):

The following does almost exactly what you want:

```
select salary
from employee
order by salary desc
offset <n> rows fetch next 1 row only;
```

The only problem is that it does not return `NULL` when there is no such salary.  You can handle using a subquery:

```
select (select salary
        from employee
        order by salary desc
        offset <n> rows fetch next 1 row only
       ) as salary;
```

If you want ties to have the same ranking, then use `select distinct salary` in the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for getting n-th highest salary, where n = 1,2,3....(int)

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM (
   SELECT TOP n salary 
   FROM employees 
   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

Hope this will help you. Below is one of the implementation.

```
create table #salary (salary int)
insert into #salary values (100), (200), (300), (400), (500)

SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM (
   SELECT TOP 3 salary 
   FROM #salary 
   ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary ASC

drop table #salary
```

The output is here 300 as 500 is first highest, 400 is second highest and 300 is the third highest as shown below

```
salary
300
```

Here n is 3

Comment: where is nth salary in your query?

Comment: You might clarify your answer please

Comment: Please check with the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296941/second-highest-salary?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: if you are getting top 3 salaries in desc then in outer main query top 1 asc query what you will get? can you clarify that?

Comment: It will produce result as Top 1 is 300  asc by default (300, 200, 100 - desc) which is the 3rd highest salary.

Comment: if it is already top 1  (300, 200, 100 - desc) then y query is ended with asc?

Comment: ASC is optional and it is by default can be avoided also.

Comment: I think the result would be 100 as you have added asc at end. can you please check it??

Comment: @ Nakul thanks for your care edited and corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

**177. Nth Highest Salary - Leetcode**

Try this out ! It worked !

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
SET N = N-1;
    RETURN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Salary as "getNthHighestSalary(2)"
    FROM Employee
    ORDER BY Salary DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET N
  
  );
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using `row_number()`

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT EmpID, Salary,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC)
    FROM Employee
)
SELECT EmpID, Salary
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = n
```

Answer (score 1):

Finds the salary for which there exist exactly 8 higher salaries, 
meaning **finds the 9th highest salary**.
Returns `NULL` if there is no 9th Salary:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.Salary FROM Employee e WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee ie WHERE ie.Salary > e.Salary) = 8
UNION 
SELECT NULL WHERE (SELECT COUNT(Salary) FROM Employee) < 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this using correlated sub-query to find Nth highest salary in Employee table..

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

Comment: care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this query and it worked

```
select sal from (select sal from employee
order by sal desc
limit n)
order by sal asc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(Salary) FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT n-1,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

### The best approach

select salary from emp as e1
where N-1 (select count(distinct salary) from emp as e2
where e2.salary > e1.salary);

Comment: Why is it THE best approach? I am sure that the community would love to have an explanation together with a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Another Possible approach.I think this could help .

```
select min(T.Salary) from
(
select distinct top n  Salary from Employee order by Salary desc
)T
```